# how to run same tasks in parallel in airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to run same tasks in parallel for different sources viz [A,B,C,D]. Following tasks are same for all the sources and currently I have repeated same code 4 times and then run them parallel, this set up is just increasing the line of code. I wanted a better way for running same task(same logic for all sources) in parallel and reduce my lines of code. may be a modular approach.

```
        delete_A_table = BigQueryDeleteTableOperator(
            task_id="delete_A_table",
            deletion_dataset_table=projectId+"."+dataSetId+".daily_A",
            ignore_if_missing=True
        )

        create_A_ext_table = BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator(
            task_id="create_A_ext_table",
            table_resource={
                "tableReference": {
                    "projectId": 'projectId1',
                    "datasetId": 'datasetId1',
                    "tableId": "daily_A",
                },
                "externalDataConfiguration": {
                    "sourceUris": "gs://loc/source_data_A"+bucket_path,
                    "sourceFormat": "AVRO",
                    "compression": "NONE",
                    "skipLeadingRows": 1,
                },
            },
        )
```

I run the following to achieve parallelism:

```
delete_C_table >> create_C_ext_table >> [trigger_C, trigger_daily_vge_report]
delete_B_table >> create_B_ext_table
delete_D_table >> create_D_ext_table
```

TIA.

==UPDATE HERE==================NEW CODE==========================

This is the actual code just replacing few tables names.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import models
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator, \
    BigQueryDeleteTableOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

extract_day = int(models.Variable.get('day'))
ext_table_names = models.Variable.get('ext_table_names')

extract_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=extract_day)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

dte = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=extract_day)
year = dte.year
mth = dte.month
day = dte.day

if day < 10:
    day = "0" + str(day)

if mth < 10:
    mth = "0" + str(mth)

bucket_path = "/year=" + str(year) + "/month=" + str(mth) + "/day=" + str(day) + "/*"

projectId = "projectId1"
dataSetId = "datasetid"

default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 3, 4),
    'email': ['atul.patil@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

with models.DAG(
        'GCS_to_BQ_ExternalTableForLoop',
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval='0 2 * * *'
        # schedule_interval=None
) as dag:
    
    for table_name in ('A', 'B','C','D'):
        delete_table_task = BigQueryDeleteTableOperator(
            task_id=f"delete_{table_name}_table",
            deletion_dataset_table=f"{projectId}.{dataSetId}.daily_{table_name}",
            ignore_if_missing=True
        )
    
        create_table_ext_task = BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator(
            task_id=f"create_{table_name}_ext_table",
            table_resource={
                "tableReference": {
                    "projectId": projectId,
                    "datasetId": dataSetId,
                    "tableId": f"daily_{table_name}",
                },
                "externalDataConfiguration": {
                    "sourceUris": f"gs://loc-{table_name}/data_{table_name}{bucket_path}",
                    "sourceFormat": "AVRO",
                    "compression": "NONE",
                    "skipLeadingRows": 1,
                },
            },
        )
        
    trigger_dag_a = TriggerDagRunOperator(
         task_id='trigger_DAG_A',
         trigger_dag_id='DAG-A',
         execution_date='{{ ds }}',
         reset_dag_run=True
    )
    
    trigger_dag_b = TriggerDagRunOperator(
         task_id='trigger_DAG_B',
         trigger_dag_id='DAG-B',
         execution_date='{{ ds }}',
         reset_dag_run=True
    )
```

Now if I gave the dependencies as follows :

`delete_table_task >> create_table_ext_task >> [trigger_dag_a, trigger_dag_b]`

gives me such graph(NOT what I need)
[image]

What I want is as follows :

```
    delete_A_table >> create_A_ext_table >> [trigger_DAG_C, trigger_DAG_D, Different_DAG]
    delete_C_table >> create_C_ext_table >> [trigger_DAG_C, trigger_DAG_D, Different_DAG]
    delete_B_table >> create_B_ext_table >> [Different_DAG]
    delete_D_table >> create_D_ext_table >> [Different_DAG]
```

This is what I need.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a fixed number of tables, and you want to run the same flow per table in parallel without code duplication; something like that can work well for you:

```
for table_name in ["A", "B"]:
    delete_table_task = BigQueryDeleteTableOperator(
        task_id=f"delete_{table_name}_table",
        deletion_dataset_table=f"{projectId}.{dataSetId}.daily_{table_name}",
        ignore_if_missing=True
    )

    create_ext_table_task = BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator(
        task_id=f"create_{table_name}_ext_table",
        table_resource={
            "tableReference": {
                "projectId": 'projectId1',
                "datasetId": 'datasetId1',
                "tableId": f"daily_{table_name}",
            },
            "externalDataConfiguration": {
                "sourceUris": f"gs://loc/source_data_{table_name}{bucket_path}",
                "sourceFormat": "AVRO",
                "compression": "NONE",
                "skipLeadingRows": 1,
            },
        },
    )

    delete_table_task >> create_ext_table_task
```

In the case of table C, where you have an extra flow, you can always do some conditions inside the loop to add the flow when needed.

EDIT based on the comments:
If you want to make all the tasks in the loop to be downstream/upstream to other tasks, you have two options:

1. use a TaskGroup; see [the following example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/_modules/airflow/example_dags/example_task_group.html).
2. You can create the downstream task before the loop and write `delete_table_task >> create_ext_table_task >> downstream_task` in the loop.

Comment: Another way to go is to create a function that generates the flow, it has more duplication but some may say it's more readable (`flow_a = create_table_flow(table_name="A")`)

Comment: But would this run in Parallel?

Comment: Yes, it would, as long as you use an Airflow executor that can run in parallel.
The for loop itself is only the creator of the flow, not the runner, so after Airflow runs the for loop to determine the flow and see this dag has four parallel flows, they would run in parallel.

Comment: It does run in parallel but not how I expect it to run. I have updated  how my task have to be running with the dependencies. Can you please check?

Comment: What you can do is to create an empty list and append in each loop iteration the last task (`create_table_ext_task`), so later you can do `task_list >> Different_DAG`

Comment: Added two options in my answer. note that the TaskGroup option is for Airflow version > 2.